# React.JS - Click event getting lost on state change due to service call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

On click of '**next**' button , I am doing a service call which will update the store and what I intend is to move to the next page. But what happens is that rerenders happens which leads to the click event getting lost.

> clientInfo.container.ts

```
const mapStateToProps = ({info}:State) => { 
     return {clientInfo}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   fetchData: () => {
     fetchClientInfo(dispatch); //Service call
   }
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClientInformation)
```

> clientInformation.tsx

```
 class ClientInfo extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
   constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
   }
   public render() {
       next: () => {
          this.props.fetchData(); //makes service call
          if (clientInfo) { // only if value is in store go to next page
            navigate({route: 'step3'}
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Probably you need to convert the component to purecomponent and handle the navigation logic in componentwillreceiveprops or getderivedstatefromprops and stop rerender via shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: To fetch data use better componentDidMount event, it's usually the best place to fetch data, then see when you get data from props inside render.